# Principal part of Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac{1+z}{e^{z^2} - 1}$ at z=0

Tags: complex-analysis

On the topic of Laurent Series, I am asked to find the principal part for the function: $f(z)=\frac{1+z}{e^{z^2} - 1}$ at z=0    Here is what I've done.

$f(z)=\frac{1+z}{e^{z^2} - 1}$

= $\frac{1}{e^{z^2} - 1}$ + $\frac{z}{e^{z^2} - 1}$

= $\frac{1}{{z^2} + \frac{z^{2^2}}{2!} + \frac{z^{2^3}}{3!} + \dots}$ + $\frac{z}{{z^2} + \frac{z^{2^2}}{2!} + \frac{z^{2^3}}{3!} + \dots}$

= $\frac{1}{z^2}(1{ + \frac{z^{2}}{2!} + \frac{z^{2^2}}{3!} + \dots)}$ + $\frac{1}{z^3}({1 + \frac{z}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \dots})$

And so the principal parts are the

$\frac{1}{z^3} + \frac{1}{z^2} +\frac{1}{2!z^2}$

Is this correct?

If it is wrong, what is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: The method is right, but your calculation went astray. The second sum should have initial term $z^{-1}$, so that there will be only two terms in the principal part. Just check your algebra.

Comment: I noticed that just now, thank you very much for your help!